# Android '\' special character

Tags: java, backslash

I have an android application where I have to find out if my user entered the special character '\' on a string. But i'm not obtaining success by using the string.replaceAll() method, because Java recognizes \ as the end of the string, instead of the " closing tag. Does anyone have suggestions of how can I fix this?
Here is an example of how I tried to do this:

```
private void ReplaceSpecial(String text) {
     if (text.trim().length() > 0) {
    text = text.replaceAll("\", "%5C");
}
```

It does not work because Java doesn't allow me. Any suggestions?

Comment: \ is special character also, so you have to close him, use \\

Comment: This is not an `android` feature. This is the feature of `Java` language

Answer (score 3):

Try this: You have to use escape character '\'

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\\\", "%5C");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\\\", "%5C");
```

`replaceAll` uses regex syntax where `\` is special character, so you need to escape it. To do it you need to pass `\\` to regex engine but to create string representing regex `\\` you need to write it as `"\\\\"` (`\` is also special character in String and requires another escaping for each `\`)

---

To avoid this regex mess you can just use `replace` which is working on literals

```
text = text.replace("\\", "%5C");
```

Answer (score 2):

`text = text.replaceAll("\", "%5C");`

Should be:

`text = text.replaceAll("\\\\", "%5C");`

**Why?**

Since the backward slash is an escape character. If you want to represent a real backslash, you should use double `\` (`\\`)

Now the first argument of [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is a *regular expression*. So you need to escape this too! (Which will end up with 4 backslashes).

Alternatively you can use [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) which *doesn't* expect a regex, so you can do:

`text = text.replace("\\", "%5C");`

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter to `replaceAll` is interpreted as a regular expression, so you actually need four backslashes:

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\\\", "%5C");
```

four backslashes in a string literal means two backslashes in the actual `String`, which in turn represents a regular expression that matches a single backslash character.

Alternatively, use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`, as recommended by [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15951159/592139), which treats its first argument as a literal string instead of a regex.

Answer (score 1):

First, since "\" is the escape character in Java, you need to use two backslashes to get one backslash. Second, since the replaceAll() method takes a regular expression as a parameter, you will need to escape THAT backslash as well. Thus you need to escape it by using

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\\\", "%5C");
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be late but not the least.

Add `\\\\` following regex to enable `\`.

**Sample regex:**

```
private val specialCharacters = "-@%\\[\\}+'!/#$^?:;,\\(\"\\)~`.*=&\\{>\\]<_\\\\"
private val PATTERN_SPECIAL_CHARACTER = "^(?=.*[$specialCharacters]).{1,20}$"
```

Hope it helps.